# jQuery click function issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some nested `<div>`s where I want to call a function on click of one of the nested `<div>`, however I am not able to achieve it.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="seat available">
  <div id="2020" class="seat-click"></div>
  <div class="tootltip-text">
    <p>Name : <span id="id31">Subham<span><button>Ok</button></span></span></p>
        <p>Seat No :<span id="13-tooltip-count">111</span></p>
        <p>Team :<span id="id32">Abc</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery :

```
$('.seat-click').on('click', function () {
        console.log('Hello');
    });
```

For clear understanding, refer to https://jsfiddle.net/47s8q2pv/4/

Here, I want the click function to be called only when I click `<div id="2020" class="seat-click"></div>`.

This can be achieved if I change the jQuery to

```
$('.seat-click').on('click', function () {
            console.log('Hello');
        });
```

If I do so, then my `<div class="tootltip-text">` will also call the same click function, which I don't want because I will have some buttons and clickable items inside the tooltip in future.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the Id instead...

Comment: For starters, your targeted element has a height of 0 - which makes it impossible to click at.

Comment: Hi @DonnieNosayaba, not working with id too

Comment: Hi @entiendoNull, can you be more clear please

Comment: as @entiendoNull said, use `.seat-click{ height:15px}`

Comment: Both of the jQuery snippets are identical except for indentation.

Comment: Thank you @entiendoNull for your help. I got it. It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @entiendoNull said, your seat-click element is of height 0.

You can either set the height of that element or write the click event handler on the seat element instead using:

```
    $('.seat').on('click', function () {
        console.log('Hello');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, i have made the height : 15px;

Answer (score 0):

The div you're using are not displayed in the browser as `<div id="2020" class="seat-click"></div>` doesn't have any width or height.

I don't understand what you want for this case, but if you want to make the button where the tooltip appears able to be clicked, maybe this is right for you

```
<div class="seat available">
  <div id="2020" class="seat-click">
  <div class="tootltip-text">
    <p>Name : <span id="id31">Subham<span><button>Ok</button></span></span></p>
        <p>Seat No :<span id="13-tooltip-count">111</span></p>
        <p>Team :<span id="id32">Abc</span></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```